# Attachment not working in creating message from AppleScript

Tags: applescript, automator

this code almost works. :) Basically I am trying to zip a file and then attach that email to a new mail message.

The process starts in automator and then the script runs.  Everything works except the actual attaching of the file.

My knowledge of AppleScript is pretty limited but trying to wrap my head around this. I combined to different code snippets to get this far.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set display_text to "Please enter your password:"
    repeat
        considering case
            set init_pass to text returned of (display dialog display_text default answer "" with hidden answer)
            set final_pass to text returned of (display dialog "Please verify your password below." buttons {"OK"} default button 1 default answer "" with hidden answer)
            if (final_pass = init_pass) then
                exit repeat
            else
                set display_text to "Mismatching passwords, please try again"
            end if
        end considering
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        set theItems to selection
        set theItem to (item 1 of input) as alias
        set itemPath to quoted form of POSIX path of theItem
        set fileName to name of theItem
        set theFolder to POSIX path of (container of theItem as alias)
        set zipFile to quoted form of (fileName & ".zip")
        do shell script "cd '" & theFolder & "'; zip -x .DS_Store -r0 -P '" & final_pass & "' " & zipFile & " ./'" & fileName & "'"
    end tell
    tell application "Finder"
        #I believe this is where the problem is, I am trying to use the variables from above in order to attach the file in mail.
        set folderPath to theFolder
        set theFile to zipFile
        set fileName to zipFile
    end tell

    set theSubject to fileName
    set theBody to "Hello sir. Here is my " & fileName
    set theAddress to "Some Email"
    set theAttachment to theFile
    set theSender to "Some Sender"

    tell application "Mail"
        set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theBody & return & return, visible:true}
        tell theNewMessage
            set visibile to true
            set sender to theSender
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:theAddress}
            try
                make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachment} at after the last word of the last paragraph
                set message_attachment to 0
            on error errmess -- oops
                log errmess -- log the error
                set message_attachment to 1
            end try
            log "message_attachment = " & message_attachment
            #send
        end tell
    end tell


    return input
end run
```

Comment: In the first `tell application "Finder"` _block_ you have `set theItems to selection` and then `set theItem to (item 1 of input) as alias`, **why!**? You are again mixing _code_ that normally isn't used together. `selection` in the context of **Finder** is what's selected in a **Finder** _window_ or on the **Desktop**. That said, questions dealing with debugging help are supposed to conform to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See #1 under [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: BTW Use **Script Editor** to help _debug_ your _code_ instead of trying to _debug_ it in **Automator**.

Comment: You are only passing the _file name_ to `make new attachment ...` and you need to pass it a _fully qualified file pathname_. (Probably as an alias too.)  Also, instead of `at after the last word of the last paragraph` you can just use: `at after last paragraph`

Comment: There are so many things wrong with your _code_. There's no validation the password not an empty _string_. There is absolutely no need for two `tell application "Finder"` _blocks_ and the only thing in the first `tell application "Finder"` _block_ should be the _code_ to get the _container_. You're double-single-quoting in the `do shell script` _command_. `./` isn't necessary as you've already changed directory and the .zip file will be created there. This is just to name a few things I see that are not right.

Comment: Thanks for the input, like I said AppleScript is new to me and I started this by building an Automator workflow. I was hoping to keep it within in that but needed more things done.

Comment: I've suggested **Script Editor** to help you _debug_ your _code_ not to abandon **Automator** altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed up most of the things that are off with your code. The following works in an automator `Run AppleScript` action if you pass in a list containing an alias to a file:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set display_text to "Please enter your password:"
    repeat
        considering case
            set init_pass to text returned of (display dialog display_text default answer "" with hidden answer)
            set final_pass to text returned of (display dialog "Please verify your password below." buttons {"OK"} default button 1 default answer "" with hidden answer)
            if (final_pass = init_pass) then
                exit repeat
            else
                set display_text to "Mismatching passwords, please try again"
            end if
        end considering
    end repeat

    tell application "System Events"
        set selected_file to item 1 of input
        set selected_file_name to name of selected_file
        set containing_folder_path to POSIX path of (container of selected_file) & "/"
        set zip_file_path to containing_folder_path & selected_file_name & ".zip"
        do shell script "cd " & quoted form of containing_folder_path & "; zip -x .DS_Store -r0 -P " & quoted form of final_pass & " " & quoted form of zip_file_path & " " & quoted form of selected_file_name
        set zip_file_alias to file zip_file_path as alias
    end tell

    set theSubject to selected_file_name
    set theBody to "Hello sir. Here is my " & selected_file_name
    set theAddress to "Some Email"
    set theSender to "Some Sender"

    tell application "Mail"
        set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theBody & return & return, visible:true}
        tell theNewMessage
            set visibile to true
            set sender to theSender
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:theAddress}
            try
                make new attachment with properties {file name:zip_file_alias} at end of attachments
            on error errmess -- oops
                log errmess -- log the error
            end try
            log "message attachment count = " & (count of attachments)
            #send
        end tell
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

Highlights:

- I switched from using the Finder to using System Events. Avoid using the Finder unless you absolutely need to (it's a very busy app)
- I set the `name` property of the attachment to an alias to the compressed file the script creates
- I cleaned up this and that to make things clearer.

Comment: Oh wow!!! I continued working on the code with your suggestions yesterday and got it to finally run about an hour ago.  But, it was much more clunky than this!!!  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ultimately came up with, which worked but the file handling for the attachment still needed work.

```
on run {input, parameters}


    tell application "Finder"
        set theItem to (item 1 of input) as alias
        set theItemCopy to theItem
        set itemPath to quoted form of POSIX path of theItem
        set fileName to name of theItem
        set theFolder to POSIX path of (container of theItem as alias)
        set zipFile to quoted form of (fileName & ".zip")
        set setPass to "Password" #test password        
        do shell script "cd '" & theFolder & "'; zip -x .DS_Store -r0 -P '" & setPass & "' " & zipFile & " ./'" & fileName & "'"
    end tell


    tell application "Mail"
        set fileLocation to (fileName & ".zip")
        set theSubject to "Subject" -- the subject
        set theContent to "Attached are the documents from the last session." -- the content
        set theAddress to "email@email.com" -- the receiver 

        set theAttachmentFile to "Macintosh HD:Users:dave:desktop:" & fileLocation -- the attachment path

        set msg to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:theSubject, content:theContent, visible:true}
        delay 1
        tell msg to make new to recipient at end of every to recipient with properties {address:theAddress}
        tell msg to make new attachment with properties {file name:theAttachmentFile as alias}


    end tell

    return input
end run
```